# how to show text while object is loading

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to show some text while my html object (a video) is loading. There used to be a standby attribute, but now that is deprecated. I'm having trouble making this simple word show up while the object is loading. What happens is that onclick, the word Loading becomes visible, then disappears while the object is loading. Does anyone know please of a quick solution?

HTML:

```
<div id="vidcontainer" class="half-embed" >
<div id="loading" style="text-align:center; color: lightgray; position: absolute; z-index:-1;width: 480px; height: 300px;">LOADING ...</div>
<img src="images/vidoverlay.jpg" style="cursor:pointer; width: 480px; height: 300px; opacity: .7; " />
</div>
```

css:

```
.half-embed
    {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:-260px;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:15px 0px;

    }
```

jquery:

```
$('#vidcontainer').click(function() {
        $('#vidcontainer img').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#vidcontainer').html("<object id='openingVideo' class='BrightcoveExperience'><param name='bgcolor' value='#FFFFFF' /><param name='width' value='480' /><param name='height' value='300' /><param name='playerID' value='xxx' /><param name='playerKey' value='xxx' /><param name='isVid' value='true' /><param name='isUI' value='true' /><param name='dynamicStreaming' value='true' /><param name='autoStart' value='true' /><param name='@videoPlayer' value='xxx' /></object>");
        brightcove.createExperiences();
});
```

Comment: It's going wrong because you're clearing everything inside `#vidcontainer` with the `.html()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could start loading the object in a hidden / zero opacity container and once your video is ready to play transition to your video.

Actually, maybe your problem is that you're overwriting the contents of your `#vidcontainer` div so your image and loading label is immediately destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

what about create object in fadeOut callback:

```
$('#vidcontainer').click(function() {
    $('#vidcontainer img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#vidcontainer').html("<object id='openingVideo' class='BrightcoveExperience'><param name='bgcolor' value='#FFFFFF' /><param name='width' value='480' /><param name='height' value='300' /><param name='playerID' value='xxx' /><param name='playerKey' value='xxx' /><param name='isVid' value='true' /><param name='isUI' value='true' /><param name='dynamicStreaming' value='true' /><param name='autoStart' value='true' /><param name='@videoPlayer' value='xxx' /></object>");
        brightcove.createExperiences();
    });
});
```

But im not sure if this is what you want, question is not clear enough for me

Comment: You dont set content after fadeOut finish, you immediately set content when is clicked, so img disapear and fadeOut effect will not work on element that doesnt exist

Comment: I'm using this structure, but I'm still working on the problem.

Comment: What I've done is fade the image very slowly (4000) with your code, then using $('#vidcontainer').append instead of $('#vidcontainer').html. Thank you!

Comment: i created 2 fiddle to compare [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFNtw/) and [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFNtw/1/) ... so as you can see its work with `.html()`